# Creating list of Objects from Database

Tags: c#, sql, database, list, object

I have 'Stolen' some code from another answer by Dummy01 in following question:
[How can I populate a list with values from a SQL Server database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10595419/how-can-i-populate-a-list-with-values-from-a-sql-server-database)

The problem is that I want to get a list of Objects instead of strings

How would I have to modify this code to do so? Help much appreciated.

The problem occurs in this part of the code where I don't know what type to specify.

```
  if (!reader.IsDBNull(0))
                        tagsList.Add(reader.GetString(0));
```

Code:

```
private void LoadList()
{
    List<string> tagsList = new List<string>();

    using (IDbConnection connection = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.DBConnectionString))
    {
        connection.Open();    

        using (IDbCommand command = connection.CreateCommand())
        {
            command.CommandText = "SELECT TAGCOLUMN FROM TAGSTABLE";

            using (IDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    if (!reader.IsDBNull(0))
                        tagsList.Add(reader.GetString(0));
                }

                reader.Close();
            }
        }

        connection.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: A string in .NET is an object. Actually all types in .NET derived form System.Object. I can't get what excalty you want. Do you mean a custom object, a class that you have declared? What? thanks

Comment: Objects of which type would you like to get in the collection?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So if you want to get a list of objects I'd submit to you that you want to use Dapper. You can get Dapper in your project via NuGet. Once you've done that you need to build a class that mimics your `SELECT` statement. For the sake of argument let's say your `SELECT` statement is:

```
SELECT * FROM TagsTable
```

and let's say `TagsTable` looks like this:

```
public class TagsTable
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Tag { get; set; }
}
```

(remember this is just to show you how it works)

Now your code looks like this:

```
private void LoadList()
{
    List<TagsTable> tagsList;

    using (IDbConnection connection =
        new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.DBConnectionString))
    {
        tagsList = connection.Query<TagsTable>(sqlStatement);
    }
}
```

Here the `Query` method is an extension method that hangs off of the `IDbConnection`; that's how Dapper works. Not only is the code concise, and the mapping done for you, but Dapper is *fast.*

Comment: I'm sorry, I need some more explanation, if you would. I Can't really seem to grasp the concept.
I need a list of <Movie>, but what to write in this part? I'm sorry for my inability to understand simple instructions :)

tagsList = connection.Query<TagsTable>(sqlStatement);

Don't understand what to switch out with own satements.

Comment: @Matt, so here TagsTable becomes Movie and the value in sqlStatement becomes a query on the Movie table. Google Dapper dot net for more instructions on the API because they can produce parameterized SQL statements with a very simple API as well (e.g. passing in a WHERE clause with filters that are parameterized).

Answer (score 0):

have you tried changing in the decalration `<string>` to `<object>`, becaus it works fine by me

Answer (score 0):

Just construct instance of the type that you want to instantiate and set it's properties according data returned by `reader` .